# append the text to the route when use enter the site

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i want when use enter the site append the `?rtl=false` or `?rtl=true` ;

i write this code in the `appcomponent.ts` :

```
this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)).subscribe(event => {
  let lang = this.translationService.getCurrentLang().lang
  if(lang==='fa')
  {
    this.router.navigate([event['url']+'rtl=true'])
  }else{
    this.router.navigate([event['url']+'?rtl=false'])
  }
});
```

but it redirect me to this url and the browser is going to hang .

`localhost:4200/apps/dahboard/user-manager?12252525252525252DUfalse26556465465465465465465465464646897489........................` .

how can i sovle this problem ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

After discussion in the comments, unfortunately, was realised that the problem belongs not to this piece of code. I've tested it on an angular app and it works as expected. You need to check other listeners on router, perhaps one of them spoils the url.

**ORIGINAL**

Looks like you missed `?` in `this.router.navigate([event['url']+'rtl=true'])`.

```js
this.router.navigate([event['url']+'rtl=true'])

this.router.navigate([event['url']+'?rtl=true']) // <- here ?
```

and the best way would be to use `queryParams`

```js
this.router.events.pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)).subscribe(event => {
  let lang = this.translationService.getCurrentLang().lang
  if (event['url'].match(/\brtl=\b/)) {
    // nothing to do, we've been redirected already
  } else if (lang === 'fa') {
    this.router.navigate([event['url']], {queryParams: {rtl: 'true'}});
  } else {
    this.router.navigate([event['url']], {queryParams: {rtl: 'false'}});
  }
});
```

Comment: it not append the `?rtl=false` to the route

Comment: show me the error `Root segment cannot have matrix parameters`

Comment: do you use `queryParams`? or simply `{rtl: 'true'}`?

Comment: still have a problem

Comment: Might you provide which one?

Comment: `localhost:4200/apps/dahboard/user-manager?12252525252525252DUfalse26556465465465465465465465464646897489........................ .

`

Comment: Then, unfortunately,  the problem belongs not to this piece of code. I've tested it on an angular app and it works as expected. You need to check other listeners on router, perhaps one of them spoils the url.